# Using random array strings to type object keys/properties - TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, generics, dynamic

I would like to have a dynamic `Array<string>` that then makes a dynamic `Object` with the `key`/`property` from the array's values. (using for a prop usage in reactjs typescript)

here's an example code:

```
interface Props {
  buttons: Array<string>;
  buttonProps?: { [key: string]: string }; //want key here to correspond with values of buttons
}
```

I am guessing you use generics here but I am unsure on how to proceed with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because key is `string` you have to add a generic, otherwise any string will be valid and it means you can put anything in buttons and in buttonProps.

I hope I got the question correctly.

```js
interface Props<T extends keyof any = keyof any> {
  buttons: Array<T>;
  buttonProps?: { [key in T]: string };
};

const buttons: Props<'test1' | 'test2'> = {
  buttons: [
    'test1', 'test2',
  ],
  buttonProps: {
    test1: 'string1',
    test2: 'string2',
  },
};
```

Comment: just a followup, what if it's a stateless react component and I want to define `buttons` elsewhere, how do I approach that?

Comment: You need a type that defines all buttons, like `type allButtons = 'test1' | 'test2'`, then you can use this type everywhere you define buttons and you can pass it to the `Props` too.

Comment: Awesome! happy coding!